# A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, delegates, garbage-collection

Error I got:

> A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type WaveLib.WaveNative+WaveDelegate::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.

My function get called from C++ DLL.

My code:

```
Public Delegate Sub MyDelegate()

<DllImport("file.dll")> Public Function FuncRegister(ByVal pFunc As MyDelegate) As Integer
End Function

FuncRegister(AddressOf MyCallback);

Public Sub MyCallback()
  counter = counter + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: How about tagging with the correct language only? Take the [tour]

Comment: It is a traditional interop bug.  Your AddressOf expression generates a delegate object on the fly.  It isn't referenced anywhere, the next GC will destroy.  Kaboom when the native code makes the callback.  You'll have to use GCHandle.Alloc() or store it in a Shared variable so the GC can always see it.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here's how to keep your callbacks alive in C#

```
public delegate void SampleCallback();

static class MyManagedAPI
{
    [DllImport("MyManagedDll.dll")]
    public static extern unsafe int RegisterCallback(void* callback);
}

unsafe static void RegisterCallback(SampleCallback callback)
{
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(callback); // keep the callback alive. Don't forget to release this later

    IntPtr pCallback = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callback);

    MyManagedAPI.RegisterCallback((void*)pCallback);
}
```